# Google Maps Api - Show all roads for specific area

Tags: android, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

As We know Google Maps shows smaller roads only on high zoom level. For example

a. Road is not visible (zoom level 12)

https://www.google.pl/maps/@52.3460727,20.4199669,12z

b. Road is visible (zoom level 17)

https://www.google.pl/maps/@52.3460727,20.4199669,17z

**Is there any posibility to highlight / show this small roads on smaller zoom level? (for specific area)**

I would like to see all roads for area

Comment: I think that resolution isn't a big problem. Please see the map of Tokyo city. There is a lot of roads. Region from my example is less complicated than view of Tokyo on 12 zoom level.

Comment: Is it with the Android or Javascript API?

Comment: do a test then. take screenshots of a map. put the images together block by block as one giant image and then shrink it to your device resolution. let me know if resolution isnt a problem, especially with the roads text (street names)

Comment: I dont want to have small roads and region in full resolution. I need just highlight small roads. I have shapes of this roads but inaccurate in gpx (external source). In zoom level 12 it looks good

Comment: Do you have any idea to export gpx / kml of all roads from small region ?